# Angular injection error in component constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

So this is my component. I want to make its count variable adjustable by user.

```js
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-likebtn',
  templateUrl: './likebtn.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./likebtn.component.css']
})
export class LikebtnComponent {
  selected: boolean = false
  count: number = 0

  constructor(count: number) {
    this.count = count;
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.selected = !this.selected
    if(this.selected)
      this.count++
    else
      this.count--
  }
}
```

I did everything I see on the internet but I still take these errors:
[image: error]

PLS HELP ME!

I did try @Inject notation, re-creating component and etc. Nothing worked. I just want to add a constructor to my component.

Comment: I don't understand why you pass the count via constructor, the correct one would be an @Input and passing it as a parameter in your component

Answer (score 0):

Angular's dependency injection system is designed for injecting services, not primitive values like numbers. If you want to allow users to adjust the count variable, you should create an @Input() property for the count value.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-likebtn',
  templateUrl: './likebtn.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./likebtn.component.css']
})
export class LikebtnComponent {
  @Input() count: number = 0;
  selected: boolean = false;

  handleClick() {
    this.selected = !this.selected;
    if (this.selected) {
      this.count++;
    } 
else{
      this.count--;
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: It did not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to inject the count from the constructor. You can remove the constructor entirely.

Comment: I want to do it in that way...

Comment: That's not how Angular works.